# Generating Strings

Tags: c, distributed-computing, brute-force

I am about creating a distributed Password Cracker, in which I will use brute force technique, so I need every combination of string.

For the sake of distribution, `Server` will give `Client` a range of strings like from `"aaaa"` to `"bxyz"`. I am supposing that string length will be of four. So I need to check every string between these two bounds.

I am trying to generate these strings in C. I am trying to make logic for this but I'm failing; I also searched on Google but no benefit. Any Idea?

**EDIT**

Sorry brothers, I would like to edit it

I want combination of string with in a range, lets suppose between `aaaa` and `aazz` that would be strings like `aaaa aaab aaac aaad ..... aazx aazy aazz` .. my character space is just upper and smaller English letters that would be like 52 characters. I want to check every combination of 4 characters. but Server will distribute range of strings among its clients. MY question was if one client gets range between `aaaa` and `aazz` so how will I generate strings between just these bounds.

Comment: You need start with a little more, like a code sample, even if it's a hello world program with one string. What are the maximum strings you would ever need? Can you tell at compile-time, or will you only know at runtime? Those are other details that will be needed, as well. Suggest you edit original post to include this information.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz I've added a pseudocode with the main idea; btw, I'm not a Sir, I'm yer brother! We're both Sirs, then (:

Comment: Stop being part of the problem and become part of the solution? If there's any justice in the World, you'll spend the best years of your life in prison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings will comprehend only the ASCII table, you'll have, as an upper limit, 256 characters, or 2^8 characters.

Since your strings are 4 characters length, you'll have `2^8 * 2^8 * 2^8 * 2^8` combinations,
or `2^8^4 = 2^32` combinations.

Simply split the range of numbers and start the combinations in each machine.

You'll probably be interested in this: [Calculating Nth permutation step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561137/calculating-nth-permutation-step)

**Edit**:

Considering your edit, your space of combinations would be `52^4 = 7.311.616` combinations.

Then, you do simply need to divide these "tasks" for each machine to compute, so, `7.311.616 / n = r`, having `r` as the amount of permutations calculated by each machine -- the last machine may compute `r + (7.311.616 % n)` combinations.

Since you know the amount of combinations to build in each machine, you'll have to execute the following, in each machine:

```
function check_permutations(begin, end, chars) {

    for (i = begin; i < end; i++) {

        nth_perm = nth_permutation(chars, i);
        check_permutation(nth_perm); // your function of verification

    }

}
```

The function `nth_permutation()` is not hard to derive, and I'm quite sure you can get it in the link I've posted.

After this, you would simply start a process with such a function as `check_permutations`, giving the `begin`, `end`, and the vector of characters `chars`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a tree containing all the permutations. E.g., like in this pseudocode:

```
strings(root,len)
    for(c = 'a' to 'z')
        root->next[c] = c
        strings(&root->next[c], len - 1)
```

Invoke by `strings(root, 4)`.

After that you can traverse the tree to get all the permutations.

Comment: he needs a range of permutations, not simply a local permutation

Comment: @Rubens the tree will contain **all** the permutations. Traversing can be parallelized.

Comment: that would be an extra cost, since each permutation, generated locally, will have to be sent for the other nodes; it's better to perform the permutations locally, considering an initial range.

Comment: @Rubens not sure I understand what you mean. The tree generation is done once. After that the traversing can be easily parallelized - each subtree can be processed by a different thread.

Comment: As he pointed, the process will be distributed, not simply parallelized; you'd have to communicate the subtrees between the initial machine and the other nodes; besides, this would be another overhead, since the permutations would be performed sequentially in one machine, to, then, be analyzed. It's noteworthy that the space of combinations has an upper bound of `2^32`.