# generate all combinations of 0's and 1's for a given length with min and max 1's given

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I would like to know if there is an efficient algorithm to generate all the combinations of 0's and 1's with length n given the minimum and maximum amount of 1's.

Example:

n=4 min=2 max=3

```
0011 0101 1001 0110 1010 1100 (with 2 1's)
0111 1011 1101 1110           (with 3 1's)
```

I know I could count in binary from (n-min)*0(min)*1 up to (max)*1 (n-max)*0 (0011 up to 1110 for the example) and take all those that
satisfy the constraints, but I would like to know if there is an algo that is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple algorithm for iterating combinations of size `n` with `k` ones:

1. Start with a bit vector of length `n`, of which the last `k` bits are `1`.
2. Repeat as long as possible (i.e. until you get a bit vector of length `n` of which the first `k` bits are `1`):
   a. Find the last `01` sequence in the bit vector. Change it to `10` and move all the following `1` bits (which must be immediately following) to the end of the sequence.

There's a simple loop-free bit-manipulation hack to do that. You can see it in my answer to this question: [Find n-th set of a powerset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713584/find-n-th-set-of-a-powerset/14717440#14717440)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but if I follow the strategy you describe in the link I get:

Comment: @rex123: I think your comment got truncated.

Comment: '0011 -> 0101 -> 1001 -> 1010 -> 1100 -> 0111 -> 1011 -> 1101 -> 1110' which means I am missing something. I think I don't understand what to do if the '1's are not immediately after '01'.

Comment: @rex123: In `0101`, the *last* `01` is at the end, so the next combination is `0110`. The `1`'s must immediately follow the last `01`, because if there are `1`'s and they don't immediately follow the last `01`, then they must follow some other `0`, so the last `01` cannot be the last `01`, proof by contradiction. The 2-sequence is: `0011`, `0101`, `0110`, `1001`, `1010`, `1100`.

Comment: Did you find this yourself or is there some theory behind this? If so at what should I look?

Comment: @rex123: I'm pretty sure I worked it out myself, just by thinking about how to iterate in lexicographical ordering. Expressing bit patterns in regex form is a weird habit of mine. :) The usual starting point for enumerations is recursion: suppose you have the solution to all problems with `(n', k') < (n, k)`, how do you then solve `(n, k)`? (eg., in this case, first iterate `0:(n-1,k)`, then do `1:(n-1,k-1)`).