# Algorithm to get every binary number of length n with m 1s

Tags: algorithm, binary, permutation, combinatorics

I'm looking for a quick way to generate every binary number of length `n` which contains `m` 1s.

So for example, if `n=3, m=2`, this would just be: `110, 011, 101`.

The naive approach would be to iterate through numbers between `1` and `2^n - 1`, checking if each value's binary representation contains `m` 1s. Alternatively, using some algorithm to get each combination of `m` 1s and `n - m` 0s.

However, I'm wondering if there might be some quicker way to do this with bitwise operators, or perhaps a property of numbers with `m` 1s in their binary representation that could be exploited.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115478/specific-binary-permutation-generating-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set)

Comment: This is identical to the problem of generating the set of n things taken m at a time (combinations). Here, the things are the positions of 1 bits.  There are gajillions of answers about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

-First you need to put a '1' in position n
-Then you need to put m-1 '1' in the positions 0 to n-1.
-You need Comb(n-1,m-1) to do this, for example using a recurring algorithm (to put m-1 '1' in n-1 positions you put a 1 in positions i= n-1 to m-2 and m-2 '1' in i-1 positions.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want only to count all possible binary numbers, then the answer will be nCm i.e C(n,m) = (n! / (m! * (n−m)!). [See here.](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php) (for an explanation of the mathematical concept: **combination.**)
2. If you need to find all numbers, then this problem is the same as: "Find all the possible Binary strings of size n having m set bits". [You can refer to this for this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075867/13898702).